# Getting the same center value of uibutton for different devices

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

When i am trying to print **btnTwo.center** its giving me (132.0, 20.0), it's not changing according to the device.I tried with iPhone SE, iPhone 8, iPhone 8Plus etc.
i even tried the below methods still the same, it seems its not taking the device dimension, it taking the default xibs dimension.

```
    viewDidAppear
    viewWillLayoutSubviews
    viewWillAppear
```

Edit - AutoLayout is working fine the buttons are arranging properly on the screen just the center remains at same position, its not changing accordingly.[image: images from iPhone 8plus and iPhone SE]

eg code -

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    signUpProgressView = SignUpProgressView.initSignUpProgressView(X: 10.0, Y: 50.0)
    self.view.addSubview(signUpProgressView!)
    signUpProgressView?.drawline()
}






public class func initSignUpProgressView(X vX:CGFloat, Y vY:CGFloat) -> SignUpProgressView{
    let bundle:Bundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder())
    let signUpProgressView:SignUpProgressView = bundle.loadNibNamed("SignUpProgressView", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! SignUpProgressView
    signUpProgressView.viewInitYCord = vY
    signUpProgressView.viewInitXCord = vX
    signUpProgressView.frame = CGRect(x: vX, y: vY, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20, height: 200)
    return signUpProgressView
}

func drawline(){

    let animatedLinelayer = AnimatedLineLayer(startPoint: btnOne.center, endPoint: btnTwo.center)

    print(btnTwo.center)
    layer.insertSublayer(animatedLinelayer, at: 0)
    animatedLinelayer.animateStrokeWithColor(color: UIColor.brown)
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code that we can understand better.

Comment: You also need to show why you think the centre should be changing. Is it because of some auto-layout constraints?

Comment: Is your button added on any other view instead of `self.view`?

Comment: And try printing the center in `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` instead of `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: tried, no result

Comment: @AbhinavJha Your button superView is?

Comment: It is stackView

Comment: Try calling this method : -"signUpProgressView?.drawline()" with a delay of 0.1 sec

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are calculating but you can calculate values using below code..

You can compare these things on different devices and get idea what to do. You can calculate X, Y values of button

```
print("button frame", btnTwo.frame)
print("button bounds", btnTwo.bounds)
print("button center", btnTwo.center)
```

Comment: Buttons position is changing on screen but still the same center